# How to pass a connection string to a constructor using Ninject's constructor injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I recently discovered the dependency-injection framework [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki) and would like to start using it in some of my projects.

I understand how to set up basic interface-to-concrete-implementation binding, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to pass arguments to the concrete implementation's constructor.

Example:

Suppose we have a simple interface to represent a customer repository:

```cs
interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer GetCustomer(int CustomerID);
}
```

And its concrete implementation:

```cs
class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private string _connectionString { get; }

    // Constructor
    public CustomerRespository(string connectionString)
    {
        this._connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    // Implements ICustomerRepository.GetCustomer
    public Customer GetCustomer(int CustomerID)
    {
        // logic to retrieve customer
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's a client of the customer repository:

```cs
class CustomerManager
{
    private ICustomerRepository _repo { get; }

    public CustomerManager(ICustomerRepository repo)
    {
        this._repo = repo;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, I'm looking for the best way to pass a connection string to `CustomerRepository`.  Using Ninject's documentation, I see that I can set up a basic binding as follows:

```cs
Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
```

However, this method doesn't allow me to send a connection string though to `CustomerRepository`.

As a work-around, I thought I'd try something like the following.  First, I set up the basic interface-to-implementation binding.  Then, I set up a special binding for the concrete implementation using a factory method to pass in the connection string.

```cs
Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
Bind<CustomerRepository>().ToMethod(context => new CustomerRepository("<connection>"));
```

The only other solution I've come across is using the `WithConstructorArgument` method.  It seems to be the obvious choice, but I'm not sure how I feel about using "magic strings" to define argument names.

```cs
Bind<ICustomerRepository>()
    .To<CustomerRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        "connectionString",
        "<connection>");
```

1. Are there other ways to pass arguments to the concrete-implementation's constructor?
2. Is there a better concrete-implementation pattern I could follow to avoid having the connection string in the constructor?

I appreciate any insights.

Comment: are you storing your connection string in appsettings.json?

Comment: Should not  `Bind<ICustomerRepository>().ToMethod(context => new CustomerRepository("<connection>"));` work? Note that it is not clear what exactly you trying to achieve/avoid at the end - both "other ways" and "better" questions you are asking are somewhat too broad for SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WithConstructorArgument` also has overloads that match to the type, not the name of the parameter, which makes it more refactor safe. Examples

- [`WithConstructorArgument<TValue>(TValue value)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/4efcbdafd2053e779564a8716f92289550aa3be2/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWithSyntax.cs#L66)
- [`WithConstructorArgument(Type type, object value)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/4efcbdafd2053e779564a8716f92289550aa3be2/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWithSyntax.cs#L74).

Usage:

```
Bind<ICustomerRepository>()
    .To<CustomerRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("<connection>");
```

I've worked on a larger project for several years and we've never used name-matching arguments, but always type matching ones.